# using events for passing parameters

Tags: c#, events

In my code,I have a `button` and a `textbox`. I want by clicking on the `button`, the value of the variable k to be sent to the `textbox`. but when I click on the button nothing happens what's wrong with my code.
here's my code.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }
        public delegate string fac(int x);
        public static fac intostring = factory;

        public static string inst= null;
        public static string factory(int x)
        {
           inst = x.ToString();
           return inst;
        }

        public delegate void myeventhandler(string newvalue);
        public class EventExample
        {
           private string thevalue;
           public event myeventhandler Valuechanged;

           public string val
           {
              set
               {
                  this.thevalue = value;
                  this.Valuechanged(thevalue);
               }          
           }
       }

 public void uu(string newvalue)
 {
   this.textBox1.Name = (newvalue);
 }

 static int k=0;
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    k = 1;
    intostring(k);
 }

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   EventExample myevt = new EventExample();
   myevt.Valuechanged += new myeventhandler(uu);
   myevt.val = inst;                          
  }
}
```

}

Comment: it converts an int to a string

Answer (score 0):

Simply set it inside of `button1_Click`

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    k = 1;
    intostring(k);
    this.textBox1.Text = thevalue;
 }
```

Comment: ur right. but this is not the whole code. i think becuase i do not use the ref keyword when the variable "inst"  changes, its change does not apply to the "val" variable so it cannot raise the event. am i right?

Comment: @user1853846 it's not clear what are you trying to achieve. can you explain?